# Regex referencing "relative" subpatterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do a regex replace such that a hyphen is inserted into each set of word pairs, from a rather long list. Simplistically, I want to make these conversions:

- double blind -> double-blind
- cost effective -> cost-effective

My initial thought was to do this:

```
str.replace(/((double) (blind)|(cost) (effective))/g,"$2-$3");
```

However, the references point to the absolute subpattern index, so "cost effective" would be deleted, not hyphenated, because the second and third subpatterns are not matched. I need something that references the first and second MATCHED subpatterns. Is this possible with Javascript regular expressions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something kind of sleazy like

```
str.replace(/((double) (blind)|(cost) (effective))/g,"$2$4-$3$5");
```

If you wanted to be a bit clearer then using a callback as the second argument to `replace` might be the way to go.

But I can't think of a way to have `$2` refer to the first match and `$3` refer to the second match no matter which of the two options you match.

Comment: Thanks - using the callback as the second argument of replace works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = /(double blind|cost effective)/g;
"double blind blahy blah cost effective".replace(regex, function (match) { return match.replace(" ", "-") });
```

You could probably stick all the phrases in the regex via a join:

```
var phrases = ['double blind', 'cost effective'];
var regex = new RegExp("(" + phrases.join("|") + ")", "g")
```

And so on. I don't know if you get that much of an improvement over simply using iterating replaces, though.